# Sprout SEO: How to access meta fields assigned to globals?

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

In the Sprout SEO docs you can pass for entries:

```
{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({
    id: entry.id
})
```

And it is smart enough to grab the data. How would could I do similar for meta fields assigned to a global set?

Comment: Mostly curious. I know the other option is to create another default. I am just looking to see if I could centralize some settings for users.

Comment: Hey Taylor, can you clarify what you mean by "meta fields assigned to a global"?  Does this mean you are trying to use a Sprout SEO Meta field type in a Global Set?

Comment: Correct. I was looking at assigning Meta Fields to a Global Set. I have a section authors edit values in a global set... thought it would easier for them to manage it in one place like an entry.

Answer (score 1):

To manage global meta data settings, we recommend using the Meta Defaults. They have all the supported fields and can be accessed by admins in the Control Panel.

The Sprout SEO Meta fields only work with Entries right now, so unfortunately, the data they store will not be usable if they are added to a Global Set.

While I understand these following items aren't exactly what you are looking to do, here are a few steps that could help customize the user experience:

1. Sprout SEO allows you to rename how the plugin is named in the interface. So you could update the plugin name to just use 'SEO' to help a client associate the SEO tab more specifically with the role of updating SEO meta data.
2. If you'd have various things setup in Globals and feel that you'd like to somehow tie in the Meta Defaults to that area of your Control Panel, the Sprout Fields plugin has a [Notes Field](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/fields/docs/overview/notes-field) that allows you to add a field that allows you to add more detailed documentation or links to a Global Set.